# How do you change the default powershell font style?

Tags: windows-7, fonts, powershell

I'm changing both Powershell and the Windows Command Prompt to use Ubuntu Mono has the default font. After installing the Ubuntu Mono Font Family and modifying the registry, both consoles pick up Ubuntu Mono Italic rather than Ubuntu Mono Regular. How could the font style be changed without simply removing the italic style?

Comment: *What changes* did you make in the registry?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I added the following key to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont: `000  REG_SZ  Ubuntu Mono`

Answer (score 1):

see

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
```

search and rename file name

```
Ubuntu Mono Italic (TrueType) REG_SZ UbuntuMono-RI.ttf
Ubuntu Mono Regular (TrueType) REG_SZ Ubuntu-R.ttf
```