# Changing font in cmd or powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe

I was looking if there was a way to change the font in command prompt or power shell? To be more exact changing it to Ubuntu Mono? Or what is the default font in Ubuntu?

Comment: Cmd (right click on header of window) -> Properties -> Font. The default font for Ubuntu is called Ubuntu.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/864212/how-do-you-change-the-default-powershell-font-style?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the shell menu by right-clicking in the upper left hand corner of the window:

[image: Shell Menu]

From there, if you would like to make a permanent change select "Defaults", to change just this session's shell select "Properties".  Both options open a similar window.  Select the "Font" tab and then select the desired font and size.

[image: Defaults Dialog]