# Strange Powershell behaviour with unicode characters

Tags: command-line, powershell, unicode

when I run the following command on a powershell window

```
echo é
```

I get the expected output

```
é
```

However, if I run

```
powershell.exe "echo é"
```

on the same powershell window as before I get

```
?
```

Is this the expected behaviour? Is it possible to change some setting so that the second command gives the correct output?

Edit: All the above was with 737 codepage. With utf-8 codepage I get

```
PS> chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

PS> powershell 'echo é'
Γ©
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing font in cmd or powershell](https://superuser.com/questions/1164189/changing-font-in-cmd-or-powershell)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. What is your code-page (use `chcp` command)?

Comment: @harrymc I get Active code page: 737

Comment: Using `chcp 737` (Greek keyboard) and typing with the french keyboard layout, typing `é` makes it look like greek gamma while I'm typing, but it echoes as `é`. We seem to be sinking deep into the mysteries of code pages and keyboard layouts.

Comment: Code pages are not keyboard layouts.